# How do I reference the object from within a $.post() call

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I've got a Javascript object that looks like:

```
var MyObject = {
   func1 : function() {
       // Does something
   },
   func2 : function() {
       // Send an AJAX request out
       $.post('', $('form').serialize(), function(response) {
           // Call the first function
           this.func1(); // Fails - this refers to the $.post request
       }, 'json');
   }
};
```

How can I make the `this` reference point to the object itself, and not to the `$.post` request?

Comment: By not using it at all: `this.func1();` => `func1();`

Comment: @SnowBlind: No, that would result in a `ReferenceError`. There is no `func1` in scope for `func2` in the above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, you're right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I reference the object from within a $.post() call

Using the variable name:

```
var MyObject = {
   func1 : function() {
       // Does something
   },
   func2 : function() {
       // Send an AJAX request out
       $.post('', $('form').serialize(), function(response) {
           // Call the first function
           MyObject.func1(); // <== Using the name
       }, 'json');
   }
};
```

See also [alexP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17923907/157247), which generalizes that a bit (e.g., if you change the name `MyObject` to something else, you don't have to do it in both places).

> How can I make the this reference point to the object itself, and not to the `$.post` request?

If you really want it to be `this`, you can do that in a couple of ways. There's jQuery's [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy):

```
var MyObject = {
   func1 : function() {
       // Does something
   },
   func2 : function() {
       // Send an AJAX request out
       //                  Note ---------v
       $.post('', $('form').serialize(), $.proxy(function(response) {
           // Call the first function
           this.func1(); // <== Using `this` now
       }, 'json'), MyObject);
       //        ^^^^^^^^^^----- note
   }
};
```

Or ES5's [`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5):

```
var MyObject = {
   func1 : function() {
       // Does something
   },
   func2 : function() {
       // Send an AJAX request out
       $.post('', $('form').serialize(), function(response) {
           // Call the first function
           this.func1(); // <== Using `this` now
       }, 'json').bind(MyObject));
       //        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----- note
   }
};
```

Note that not all browsers have ES5's `bind` yet, although it's one of the features that can be shimmed (search for "es5 shim" for several options).

Comment: Actually why isn't `this` refering to the callback function given to `$.post` instead of `$.post` itself ? Cause when you declare an object type using `var Foo function() { };` using `this` in the function refers to the function itself. EDIT i'm gonna make a question of this.

Comment: You rock T.J.! Exactly the answer I was looking for

Comment: @Virus721: `this` very, very rarely refers to functions. As for `$.post`, the documentation doesn't say what it sets `this` to during the callback.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way:

```
var MyObject = {
   func1 : function() {
       // Does something
   },
   func2 : function() {
       var self = this;        //self = MyObject-object
       // Send an AJAX request out
       $.post('', $('form').serialize(), function(response) {
           // Call the first function
           self.func1(); // #### NEW ####
       }, 'json');
   }
};
```

Comment: +1 Not sure why I didn't include that option, it's what I would *normally* do (down to the name of the var!).

Comment: Sometimes less is more :-) `var that = this;`

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax context option:

```
$.ajax({
  context:this,
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: this.func1,
  dataType: dataType
});
```